# Is there a way to make AutoGK to resize the video?

Tags: youtube, avi, aspect-ratio, virtualdub

AutoGK is so far a good tool for converting video clips in DVD-R disc into .avi to post to YouTube.

But I captured some Wii game play, and it is 16 : 9 ratio, but AutoGK only output the .avi in 4 : 3 ratio.  Is there actually a way to tweak it to output the avi as 16 : 9?

Otherwise, I need to run VirtualDub and download DivX codec to run it again to resize it 16 : 9.

Any way this is done, or any other recommendations?  thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try this with TMPGEnc and convert it to 16:9

Here are some guides:

http://tmpgenc.pegasys-inc.com/en/product/taw4_tutorial/taw4_tu_index.html

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest you switch to [meGUI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/megui/)

AutoGK has not been updated in a very long time now. I switched to meGUI quite some time ago - it does everything AutoGK did and more and is actively developed.

It has many options for handling aspect ratios.